# Google Spreadsheets: - Validating cell contains only alphanumeric and underscore

Tags: google-sheets, validation, re2

In Google Spreadsheets, how do I use a custom formula (with [re2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax) regular expression) to only allow alphanumeric and underscore characters in cell content?

Answer (score 3):

I needed a Validation which would detect this also. Here's my working solution.

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+"), FALSE, TRUE)`

This Regex validation `[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+` returns TRUE if anything is present in the string EXCEPT for letters, numbers, underscores and dashes (The `^` asserts a 'negated set')

Then we simply flip the boolean logic (using 'IF...FALSE,TRUE'). This results rejection of *illegal* characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main formulas used for validating a regular expression (you can find the formula documentation [HERE](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)):

- REGEXEXTRACT : Extracts matching substrings according to a regular expression.
- REGEXMATCH : Whether a piece of text matches a regular expression.
- REGEXREPLACE : Replaces part of a text string with a different text string using regular expressions.

You can use these formulas to test expressions. This page should help you learn about how to take advantage of these formulas [Regular Expressions - Part 1](http://www.javascript-spreadsheet-programming.com/2013/09/regular-expressions.html). Also check out the regular expressions part 2.

*Alternatively, if you are using a Google Form to submit data to your spreadsheet, you can add field validation for each question.*

Comment: I tried REGEXMATCH before posting the question. My question is _what is the correct regular expression_.

Comment: Here's an re2 reference: https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html

Most regular expressions for an alphanumeric sequence with underscores would look something similar to [a-zA-Z0-9_]* where:

a-z = lowercase letter
A-Z = any uppercase letter
0-9 = any digit
_ : underscore

I placed the * to denote 0 or more of the alphanumeric characters. If you want the string to be a certain length or pattern, take a look at the repetitions section of the above reference.

Comment: @Orion if you're insisting on getting correct Regex, maybe you should have tagged your question to be ABOUT regex. The fact you 'Tried RegexMatch before posting', failed to flag the question is about Regex, then misquoted what your actual question is about (your question is NOT 'what is the correct regular expression') makes me think you're just baiting people to do work for you. Thats not what StackOverflow is here for. Brady's regex in his response should work in conjunction with 'RegexMatch'. He probably didn't post it as an answer because you didn't flag this as a Regex question